# Select similar columns from different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, multiple-tables

I have 2 tables that have some columns which are very similar.

The first table, `paypal_orders`, has the following columns, and let's say it has 15 records:

- transaction ID
- amount
- status
- date
- payer_email

The second table `cod_orders` has the following columns, and let's say it has 10 records:

- id
- amount
- status
- date
- customer_id

I was thinking of using `SELECT INTO...` but discovered that MySQL's support for it only extends to user defined variables and outfiles.

Is it possible to make a SELECT statement that can give an output of 25 records, displaying only the columns that are common to both tables (with an additional "type" column):

- type (where type is either `paypal` or `cod`)
- amount
- status
- date

So the first 15 records will be the paypal orders, with type "paypal", and the next 10 will be the cod orders, with type = "cod".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `union` should allow you to get both result sets.

```
(select 'paypal', amount, status, date, transaction_id 
                                                   from paypal_orders limit 15)
union
(select 'cod', amount, status, date, id 
                                     from cod_orders limit 10)
```

**SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/037e5/3

Comment: why thank you so much!!! :) I made a small adjustment: I added *select 'paypal' as 'type'* and *select 'cod' as 'type'* to rename the column name for that.

Comment: @user961627 Glad I could help, I updated the query and example to pull 10 and 15 records.

Comment: @KevinBowersox . . . You should always use `union all` instead of `union`, unless you very intentionally want to do the extra work of removing duplicates.